# How to use ON DUPLICATE KEY on hsqldb 2.3.4

Tags: hsqldb, upsert

According to the update on hsqldb.org listed here: http://hsqldb.org/web/features200.html

It now supports the mysql syntax ON DUPLICATE KEY in hsqldb 2.3.4, yet Im still getting sql errors when trying to run it. If im reading correctly I may need to set certain flags. But I cant find what to set to be able to use this synatx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL compatibility is documented in the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_mysql

You need to execute `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE` or the equivalent URL property `sql.syntax_mys=true` to enable it.