# HSQLDB ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax error

Tags: insert, sql-insert, hsqldb, upsert

I try to execute following query:

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE;
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, age) VALUES (1, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=2, age=33;
```

I get error:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, age) VALUES (1, 1)
               ON DUPLICATE KEY
[2020-10-23 11:09:42] [42590][-5590] unexpected end of statement:  required: UPDATE : line: 2
```

What do I wrong ?

Comment: I almost feel like maybe MySQL syntax mode isn't being enabled for some reason.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen how can I check it ?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen

PUBLIC.PUBLIC> SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE
[2020-10-23 11:23:14] completed in 4 ms
PUBLIC.PUBLIC> INSERT INTO tblUserMetadata (userMetadataId, portalId) VALUES (1, 1)
               ON DUPLICATE KEY
[2020-10-23 11:23:14] [42590][-5590] unexpected end of statement:  required: UPDATE : line: 2

Comment: Can you try running this: `SELECT 'true' WHERE 'Hello World' REGEXP '^H.*d$';` ?  Let's try to verify some other way that MySQL syntax is kicking in.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleise

PUBLIC.PUBLIC> SELECT 'true' WHERE 'Hello World' REGEXP '^H.*d$'
[2020-10-23 11:25:45] [42581][-5581] unexpected token: WHERE

Comment: [But this query is in fact a valid MySQL query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a865eb7a8cb435d20b0d1911a201fca3) as the demo link shows.  I speculate that you're _not_ running in MySQL mode `:-)`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Maybe see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937669/how-to-use-on-duplicate-key-on-hsqldb-2-3-4

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Didn't help for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The OP reports this in a comment:

```
PUBLIC.PUBLIC> SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX MYS TRUE [2020-10-23 11:23:14] completed in 4 ms 
PUBLIC.PUBLIC> INSERT INTO tblUserMetadata (userMetadataId, portalId) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY [2020-10-23 11:23:14] [42590][-5590] unexpected end of statement: required: UPDATE : line: 2
```

The lines show an SQL client is being used to run a script. The SQL client pre-parses the statement and thinks the statement is finished after the keyword `KEY`, and the keyword `UPDATE` is the start of a new statement. So it tries to send the incomplete SQL query to the database engine.

The MySQL syntax is in operation because the command was accepted and executed.

You can check the property settings by selecting from a system table:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.system_properties
```

The statement below returns `true` when the MySQL compatibility mode has been set:

```
SELECT property_value FROM information_schema.system_properties 
    WHERE property_name = 'sql.syntax_mys'
```